# How can my LaTeX files detect if they're being compiled on Overleaf?

Tags: conditionals, overleaf

I have a LaTeX file that executes an external shell command to get some information; this works on my local machine but fails on Overleaf. That's okay, not a big deal—if I can wrap the code in an if-then conditional that checks if it's executing on Overleaf.

Problem: how can I make my LaTeX code check if being run on Overleaf?

Clarification added 2017-07-31: I already know how to test for shell escapes, and conditionalize my code appropriately.  The problem is not whether shell escapes work; the problem is really about testing for Overleaf versus other environments.

Comment: surely you don't want o know if it's on overleaf but if shell escape is enabled?, which you can test for the integer value of `\pdfshellescape` or `\shellescape` or in lua `status.shell_escape` dependin on the tex flavour in use.

Comment: No; in fact, shell escapes *do* work, and I already test for that in my code. But the command involves getting information using git, and this works differently in my local environment versus in Overleaf. I have given up trying to figure out why the command fails. I just want to skip the whole thing when running on Overleaf.

Comment: oh in that case you could shell escape and look at the environment variables, surely overleaf must have some environment  variable set with a distinguished value?

Comment: That would work, but I have not found anything relevant in their documentation so far. I was hoping someone here would have already done something like this and knew the answer.

Comment: just look at the output of the command `env` and pick one:-)

Comment: even simpler yet---the \jobname for Overleaf seems to be 'output'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to determine the home path used by Overleaf and test against that. It's unlikely to match your local home path.

To find Overleaf's home path:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\begingroup\endlinechar=-1\relax
       \everyeof{\noexpand}%
       \edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\homepath{%
         \@@input|"kpsewhich --var-value=HOME" }}\x
\makeatother

\begin{document}
HOME: \texttt{\homepath}.

\end{document}
```

Then copy the resulting path and test against that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\begingroup\endlinechar=-1\relax
       \everyeof{\noexpand}%
       \edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\homepath{%
         \@@input|"kpsewhich --var-value=HOME" }}\x
\makeatother

\def\overleafhome{/home/whatever}% change as appropriate

\begin{document}
\ifx\homepath\overleafhome
 Overleaf.
\else
 Not Overleaf.
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: I used this approach. Based on some testing, that path on Overleaf appears to be `/home/wl`. Thank you very much for this solution.

Comment: Addendum: I examined other environment variables, per David Carlisle's comments at the top. Unfortunately, no other variable other than `HOME` seemed safe enough to use (in the sense that I couldn't be sure a collaborator would get the expected behavior if the used the files in _their_ local environment).

Comment: Any suggestions on making this work under windows as well? Unfortunately the `\ ` 
 in the windows path causes the error `:1: Undefined control sequence.
l.1 C:\Users`. I tried piping the output of kpsewhich to `tr`, but couldn't figure out how to send it `\ ` symbols.

Comment: @kgoodrick I have the same problem. Have you been able to resolve It?

Answer (score 4):

Just like some others, I was struggling with Windows compatibility because of paths containing backslashes.
I found a solution by combining *ivo Welch*'s suggestion of looking at the jobname with [this](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-compjobnam):

```
\def\StripPrefix#1>{}
\def\jobis#1{FF\fi
    \def\predicate{#1}%
    \edef\predicate{\expandafter\StripPrefix\meaning\predicate}%
    \edef\job{\jobname}%
    \ifx\job\predicate
}

\if\jobis{output}%
    Overleaf.
\else
    Not Overleaf.
\fi
```

It works because overleaf has a fixed jobname of `output`. Your local build probably uses the `.tex` filename.

**EDIT:** alternatively, a bit cleaner:

```
\def\StripPrefix#1>{}
\def\isOverleaf{\fi
    \def\overleafJobname{output}% overleaf defaults to 'output' as \jobname
    \edef\overleafJobname{\expandafter\StripPrefix\meaning\overleafJobname}%
    \edef\job{\jobname}%
    \ifx\job\overleafJobname
}

\if\isOverleaf%
    Overleaf.
\else
    Not Overleaf.
\fi
```

Comment: With recent versions of LaTeX, it's bit easier to use : `\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_if_eq:VnTF \c_sys_jobname_str {output} {Overleaf} {Not~Overleaf}
\ExplSyntaxOff`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/598669 is even cleaner