# Using tikzsetnextfilename for naming external tikz-files disables tikzscale

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

To implement the approach discussed here: [Automatic detection of Overleaf for fallback images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/596258/automatic-detection-of-overleaf-for-fallback-images) I wanted to give my tikz-files their own names, such that I can either include the tikz-file when compiling locally or the pdf-file when working on overleaf (which is significantly easier when knowing the file name of the PDF beforehand). Therefore, I included `tikzsetnextfilename` in my tikzfiles. Unfortunately, that seems to disable the scaling possibility given by `includegraphics` and `tikzscale`. As example, with two files `main.tex` and `sub.tikz`:

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\begin{filecontents*}{file1.dat}
    x y
    0 0
    1 1
    2 2
    3 3
    4 4
    5 5
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz-cache/]
\tikzset{external/force remake}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        label style={font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
        tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
        legend style={font=\footnotesize}
    },
    y axis/.append style={align=center}}
\tikzset{Line Label/.style={font=\footnotesize,scale=2}}
\newcommand{\figurefontsize}{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htpb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=7\linewidth]{sub.tikz}
        \caption{Image I}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

sub.tikz:

```
\pgfplotstableread{file1.dat}{\tablea}
\tikzsetnextfilename{sub}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
        ymin=0, ymax=30,
        xmin=0, xmax=5,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        grid=major,
        legend entries={\(y_1\),\(y_2\),\(y_1+y_2\)},
        legend pos = north west
        ]
        % Select appropriate columns
        \addplot [blue, mark=*] table [x=x,y=y] {\tablea};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

When disabling tikzsetnextfilename, scaling works, and the graph is scaled appropriately. Enabling it leads to a fixed scaling factor of 1, though, without any log errors or warnings. Is there a solution or an explanation (or possibly both)?

Answer (score 1):

For me, moving `\tikzsetnextfilename{extname}` out and before the `\includegraphics[opts]{filename.tikz}`, rather than having it *inside* `filename.tikz` solved the problem.