# Redefinition of \includegraphics for inclusion of default figure fails

Tags: graphics, external-files, includegraphics, tikzscale

In an earlier question ([Automatic detection of Overleaf for fallback images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/596258/61517)) I wanted to automatically detect if I am on Overleaf or locally to choose fallback images when on Overleaf, or to re-compile locally.
The initial approach was done using the following code:

```
    \begin{figure}[htpb]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\linewidth}
            \ifdefined\TestFigures
                \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \else
                \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \fi
            \caption{Image I}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill%
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \ifdefined\TestFigures
                \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \else
                \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \fi
            \caption{Image II}
        \end{subfigure}%
    \end{figure}
```

Nevertheless, doing that will lead to quite a lot of code, and make it easy to forget something. Therefore, I decided to redefine `includegraphics` with

```
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2]{\ifdefined\TestFigures%
    \includegraphics[#1]{example-image-a}
    \else
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
    \fi%
}
```

and use the following code in the main document:

```
\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{sub.tikz}
    \caption{Image I}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{sub.tikz}
    \caption{Image II}
    \end{subfigure}%
\end{figure}
```

This fails with `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].`, presumably due to a definition loop. Therefore, I tried to avoid it by changing the initial definition of `includegraphics` to

```
\LetLtxMacro{\includelateximages}{\includegraphics}
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2]{\ifdefined\TestFigures%
    \includelateximages[#1]{example-image-a}
    \else
    \includelateximages[#1]{#2}
    \fi%
}
```

but this fails with

```
! Package xkeyval Error: `[' undefined in families `Gin'.
```

What exactly is going wrong here, and how can I simplify my initial approach else?

Now, as suggested in the comments, I included optional arguments (instead of only mandatory arguments) and renamed `\includegraphics` to check other error sources, resulting in the following code for the main file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz-cache/]
\tikzset{external/force remake}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        label style={font=\Large\bfseries},
        tick label style={font=\Large},
        legend style={font=\Large}
    },
    y axis/.append style={align=center}}
\tikzset{Line Label/.style={font=\Large,scale=2}}
\newcommand{\figurefontsize}{\Large}

\newcommand{\TestFigures}{1}
\LetLtxMacro{\includegraphicsorig}{\includegraphics}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\includegraphics}{O{} m }{%
    \ifdefined\TestFigures%
        \includegraphicsorig[#1]{example-image-a}%
    \else%
        \includegraphicsorig[#1]{example-image-b}%
    \fi%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\includeOLgraphics}{O{} m }{%
    \ifdefined\TestFigures%
    \includegraphicsorig[#1]{example-image-a}%
    \else%
    \includegraphicsorig[#1]{#2}%
    \fi%
}

\begin{filecontents}{file1.dat}
    x y
    0 0
    1 1
    2 2
    3 3
    4 4
    5 5
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htpb]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{sub.tikz}
        \caption{Image I}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill%
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{sub.tikz}
        \caption{Image II}
        \end{subfigure}%
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[htpb]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\linewidth}
            \includeOLgraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{sub.tikz}
            \caption{Image I}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill%
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includeOLgraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{sub.tikz}
            \caption{Image II}
        \end{subfigure}%
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

For the case of the first sub-figure I do not get any error messages, but neither does it change when defining or un-defining the key `TestFigures`. For the case of the second sub-figure it works fine if I enable `TestFigures`, but fails with `LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .tikz.` if I disable it, indicating that I might be messing with the changes done in `tikzscale` (which redefines `includegraphics`, too). Are there solutions to that?

Comment: Call your command something else, your code leads to circular expansions until you run out of memory. And include graphics takes two arguments first of which is optional. You define it with two mandatory arguments.

Comment: In addition to daleif's comment: Try something like `\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics` to save the original version of the command. Then redefine it like `\renewcommand\includegraphics{...\oldincludegraphics...}` because otherwise you will have an "endless" recursion (well it ends when you run out of memory).

Comment: @Οὖτις `\let` would not work here that is why the OP used `\LetLtxMacro` or in a current latex format you could use `\CopyCommand`

Comment: @Οὖτις: I included your suggestions, but apparently I am messing now with some parts of `tikzscale` which are giving me some headache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I found a solution, by delaying my redefinition to the beginning of my document:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
\LetLtxMacro{\includegraphicsorig}{\includegraphics}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\includegraphics}{O{} m }{%
    \ifdefined\TestFigures%
        \includegraphicsorig[#1]{example-image-a}%
    \else%
        \includegraphicsorig[#1]{#2}%
    \fi%
}%
}
```

Now it works as expected, if `\TestFigures` is defined, the example figures are used, if not, the included figures are loaded.