# How to check that I'm compiling using Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf

Is there a simple (boolean) test to check that the document is being compiled on Overleaf (vs elsewhere, i.e. local computer via git download)

Use case (one example) : I'm using fonts that are available only on my laptop and I want Overleaf to fall back to a common font (e.g. free font)

Comment: Maybe you could use `\IfFileExists` to check for the font file

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30617/36296 might give you some ideas

Comment: If you just want to test whether or not you compile on your own computer, you don't even have to know what the font file is, you could test for any file which overleaf won't have, e.g. `~/My_love_letter_to_TeX.txt` in your home folder...

Comment: Some other ideas: if you happen to use another operating system than overleaf, you could use the `ifplatform` package. Overleaf also uses an old texlive version, assuming your system is up to date, you could check the kernel version.

Comment: I think testing whether the font file exists should be the way to go, since this is actually the test you are interested in.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/596258/36296

Answer (score 3):

Given the usecase mentioned, it seems more prudent to check if the font exists, and if not, to load the fallback font.

To do that, I would recommend the method used in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438768/234004) using the `fontspec` package.

In your case, the MWE from that answer would be changed slightly to:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438577/86}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% Check to see if this font is installed system-wide
\IfFontExistsTF{TeX Gyre Termes}{%
% One person has this installed system-wide
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
}{
% If not, load it from the file
  \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
}

\begin{document}
Wouldn't it be nice if this were Termes?
\end{document}
```

replacing TeX Gyre Termes with the font you want to check for and Latin Modern Roman with the font you want to fall back to.

The other possibility is to put the font file into the project directory, assuming you have an .otf or .ttf, and load it using `fontspec` with `\setmainfont{texgyretermes-regular.otf}`. This should work on Overleaf as well as locally.

Comment: "% Check to see if this font is installed system-wide"

This doesn't work if the font is not already known to the system. i.e local font (say in ./TTFfont/...) and loaded via Path attribute...
Am I wrong ?

Comment: sorry, I don't quite understand the question. The \IfFontExistsTF command will check if the font you specify is known to your TeX engine, return true/false accordingly.

Comment: but if you have the font file, I think the most robust way to do this is to put it in the project directory and load it manually.