# Deal with back slash in Window's path

Tags: pdftex

I am trying to achieve the same goal as this thread: [How can my LaTeX files detect if they're being compiled on Overleaf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384066/how-can-my-latex-files-detect-if-theyre-being-compiled-on-overleaf).

However, the `\homepath` kept throwing the error as follows:

```
Undefined control sequence.
C:\Users\USER
```

How can I resolve this issue on Windows? I believe some modifications need to be made in the following code block but have no ideas what to do...

```
\makeatletter
\begingroup\endlinechar=-1\relax
       \everyeof{\noexpand}%
       \edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\homepath{%
         \@@input|"kpsewhich --var-value=HOME" }}\x
\makeatother
```

Comment: I found another solution, take a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/650621/236875) answer. It works by looking at the `\jobname` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `\ifwindows` from the `ifplatform` package to skip the path lookup on Windows and just assign some dummy path. This package needs shell escape for detecting the difference between Linux and Mac but not for the `\ifwindows` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifplatform}
\makeatletter
\ifwindows\def\homepath{windows}\else
\begingroup\endlinechar=-1\relax
       \everyeof{\noexpand}%
       \edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\homepath{%
         \@@input|"kpsewhich --var-value=HOME" }}\x
\fi
\makeatother

\def\overleafhome{/home/whatever}% change as appropriate

\begin{document}
Homepath: \homepath

\ifx\homepath\overleafhome
 Overleaf.
\else
 Not Overleaf.
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that I can't test this answer because I don't have Windows available but it should work to avoid the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thank you so much! It solves the problem!