# Same font has different name locally and on Overleaf. How to make document compile on both?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, overleaf, document-classes

I am building a document class and I am using [these](https://github.com/IBM/plex/releases) fonts. Unfortunately, after an update the style naming convention changed slightly e.g. `Medium` is now `Medm` and `SemiBold` is now `SmBld`. This has not been updated on Overleaf though and when compiling there, the process break. How can I make it compile consistently across platforms.

Minimum example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

% This works locally, but breaks on Overleaf
% \setmainfont{IBM Plex Sans SmBld}
% This works on Overleaf but breaks locally
\setmainfont{IBM Plex Sans SemiBold}

\begin{document}
  Hello with IBM Plex Semi Bold!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably [Can fontspec provide a fallback font if a font doesn't exist?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438577/106162) but maybe [How can my LaTeX files detect if they're being compiled on Overleaf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/384066/106162)

Comment: Upload on Overleaf the font (You could add it in a folder named `Fonts` or something and use the optional argument `Path=./Fonts/IBM Plex Sans SmBld/`)

Comment: Do try `\IfFontExistsTF` as mentioned in the first linked comment. I use it for a similar purpose (but nothing to do with Overleaf). It works.